# Get elements of set excluding some

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

```
dic = {'a': {1, 2, 3}, 'b': {5, 6, 7}}
print(dic['a'])
```

How can I get the printed result to exclude 1 (not to remove) to be:

```
{2,3}
```

Comment: Do you want to exclude number 1, or first item of every set?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi numer 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could subtract `{1}` from the inner set:

```
print(dic['a'] - {1})
{2, 3}
```

Or equivalently you can use `difference`:

```
print(dic['a'].difference({1}))
{2, 3}
```

You can learn more about the topic on [sets — Unordered collections of unique elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: Nice and simple.

Comment: This is the best way since it has O(1) complexity.